# How to store all the data from struct to a new array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm programming in C language and I have this struct.

```
struct value
{
    unsigned char time[18];
    unsigned char date[18];
    unsigned char number[18];
} entry;
```

Now I want to store all the data from there to an array `a[54]` where I want to store

```
a[0] = entry.time[0];
a[1] = entry.date[0];
a[2] = entry.number[0];
```

What could be the best way to do so?
apart from for loop.

How will these elements stored in  memory and is there better way to access them using pointers?

Comment: You just answered your own question...

Comment: Have you tried a loop? Since you'll be copying continuous pieces of data to discontinuous locations there isn't much language support for doing this automatically.

Comment: .Well sorry for my poor communication skills.well apart from for loop how can i at a stretch store all the values in to a[54]

Answer (score 4):

Well that's easy.

```
for (i = 0; i < 18; i++)
{
    a[i*3] = entry.time[i];
    a[i*3 + 1] = entry.date[i];
    a[i*3 + 2] = entry.number[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Akash . I was wondering any other way to access data.Sorry for my poor clarity in question.I  hope it's clear now